# Extracting data from text files using python

Tags: python, text-extraction

I have a text file which contains a line like this:

```
Component Sizing Information, AirTerminal:SingleDuct:VAV:Reheat, SPACE2-1 VAV REHEAT, Design Size Maximum Flow per Zone Floor Area during Reheat [m3/s-m2], 1.31927E-003
```

I want to extract the number at the end of the line (1.31927E-003) when the statement before the number is (just an example!):

```
Design Size Maximum Flow per Zone Floor Area during Reheat [m3/s-m2]
```

In fact, there are several of these key statements in the text file which I need to extract the numbers coming right after them, respectively.

What library and method do you recommend? (using python 3). Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all your lines are similar, you can split the original line and extract the number as :

```
string = "Component Sizing Information, AirTerminal:SingleDuct:VAV:Reheat, SPACE2-1 VAV REHEAT, Design Size Maximum Flow per Zone Floor Area during Reheat [m3/s-m2], 1.31927E-003"
string = string.split(',')          #split the string at commas
number = string[-1]                 #Extract the last number.
number = number.strip()             #remove extra white spaces
```

Answer (score 2):

## Re Module

Python has a regular expressions module that is useful for programmatic pattern-based extraction from text.

[re](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) is the regular expressions module in *Python 3*.

This is a pattern that would work for your specific case (but may need to be changed depending on the consistency of your string)

---

## Pattern

Figure out the pattern that works for your case - in your case, we can identify the following:

- You have a number which can have whole numbers ranging from 0-9 repeated:

  ```
  `[0-9]+`
  ```
- You have a decimal point:

  ```
  `\.` # \ is used as an escape character for a literal . as . has a use in regex
  ```
- you have a string of numbers and it contains the letter `E` and a hyphen `-`

  ```
  `[0-9E-]+`
  ```

Combining these features in sequential order:

`pattern = r'[0-9]+\.[0-9E-]+'`

**Note** that often the `r'...'` before a string is in many regex examples - the `r` represents a raw string that deals better with potential escape characters in the string.

---

## REGEX in Python

We need to compile this as a regex (regular expression) object:
`prog = re.compile(pattern)`

The `findall` method will return a list of all strings (that do not overlap) - There are other methods such as `re.search` and `re.match` which have other specific outputs:

```py
results = re.findall(prog, your_string)
```

---

## TEST

```py
import re
mystr = 'Component Sizin1..31927J-003ggnoor' \
        ' Ar1.31927E-003ea' \
        ' du' \
        'rin1g.31927E-003g Re' \
        'he1.t31927E-003at ' \
        '[m3/s-m1.34545457E-0032], 1.3' \
        '191.31927E-00327' \
        'E-01...31927E-00303'

pattern = r'[0-9]+\.[0-9E-]+'
prog = re.compile(pattern)
results = re.findall(pattern, mystr)
print(results)

.........

['1.31927E-003', '1.34545457E-0032', '1.3191']
```

To learn regular expressions take practice (and a good interactive environment) - such as [regex101](https://regex101.com/)